# How to use a PHP Fastcgi process from CLI

Tags: sockets, cgi, fastcgi, php

I have PHP running via Fastcgi on Apache2.  The PHP process uses a Unix Socket.

Would it be possible to access the socket from the command line and to execute a PHP script?

I have some long running operations that can take hours to execute, so going via the webserver is not an option.  On the other hand, calling PHP from the command line directly is not optimal, because the CLI process cannot access the shared caches of the fastcgi php process.

I tried the socket command, but I do notreally know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working with cgi-fcgi.